# Creating a "sure to run" app / installer in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I need to create a simple installer of sorts for a different application. That other application already has it's own simplistic installer, and I don't want to meddle with it.

The reason for my own installer is to allow the user to install SQL Express if (s)he so chooses, and also to pre-install any other basic requirements for such a procedure.

At the moment, here's where I'm at:
I've created a single Windows form application, with big buttons (this is for a user which likely won't be very good with computers) to install SQL Server Express (using silent install with a predefined set of arguments) or the actual application, along with some helpful text to let the user know what's going on. Something along the lines of Visual Studio autorun window.
I've also added the standard set of pre-requirements to the application (.NET, Windows Installer).

Everything works OK if I run the app by using the executable. HOWEVER, if I publish it to create a ClickOnce application (so the pre-requisites are installed when needed) and run it, it stops running other installers.

EDIT: Apparently the problem with not being able to run other application from a ClickOnce application is only on my end, and probably deserves a new question, not necessarily here on StackOverflow (perhaps on MSDN forums?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled for a "Click Once" application. It can install all required .NET components needed for it to run, thus becoming an "sure-to-run-non-native-C++-code-splash-screen".

Granted, there ARE issues with Click Once, but this is far better than nothing. It's also better than running C++ or unmanaged code applications. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your program before launching the installer you can check if .NET is installed. Its pretty easy to check if a particular s/w or a version of s/w is installed. Write a program that will check HKEY/LocalMachine/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall and in that there will be list of programs that have been installed on that machine. If you find then go ahead with your install else suggest user that he needs to install pre req.

When you create a setup project you can right click on the setup project, go to properties, and click on pre requisites. In that you can mention which version of .NET framework is needed and then give the location of the framework. In this link look for Huggy Bears response eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10131905/setup-project.aspx

Comment: But that program might not be able to launch, as it's a .NET application itself!  The point is to create something that is SURE to work, and as such, it should install .NET if needed.

Comment: For that you have to write setup in unmanaged code. You will find examples of it on msdn. You can look it over here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994395.aspx. In that go down to Creating a Single Setup Project to Install a .NET Framework Application and Dotnetfx.exe

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I still don't quite understand your idea. I should create an unmanaged code application that will check for the existence of .NET and run the .NET setup if it is not present then launch the full splash screen? If so, then I must admit I have absolutely no skill in creating unmanaged code applications, but to my understanding, the Windows Installer will always run and install whatever is needed. It can also run another application (this is what I've been working on for the majority of the day so far :P) and I'm just faced with forcing it to rollback the install...

Comment: PS. The link you provided seems to be quite old and the sample code that's linked in it no longer seems to exist...

Comment: try this link. Google is your friend. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=BF253CFD-1EFC-4FC5-BA7E-6A6F21403495&displaylang=en

Comment: When you create a setup project you can right click on the setup project, go to properties, and click on pre requisites. In that you can mention which version of .NET framework is needed and then give the location of the framework. In this link look for Huggy Bears response http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10131905/setup-project.aspx

Comment: It seems all that was needed was to create a Click-once "online" application with .NET as a pre-requirement. I assumed I had to create an installer to actually install .NET, but that, as already stated, creates an Add/Remove entry which isn't needed for a "Startup/installer/splash screen".

Comment: ...of course now I'm tasked with running another application from within a click-once application...

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. You asked how to check if .NET is installed and install it before your application is installed. I edited my answer to show that. What do you mean by running another application from within a click one app?

Comment: Hey if this in anyway has helped you can mark it as answer or upvote it.

Comment: I'll edit the main question. Your comment was helpful, the answer you posted was not (albeit it might be because my question wasn't clear enough to begin with).

Comment: sadly upvoting my comments would not fetch me any points :(. The driving force for me to put some time on SO is that I learn new things which btw I did through your question, and also the rep score :)

Comment: I guess I cannot be of any more help from hereon and you have to wait for more .NET experts to answer your question. OR create a new question if this question has gone down in the stack so that people will see.

Comment: Well, if you hold StackOverflow point so close to your heart... :D